# SQL working as query, but failing when calling as a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this SQL, that is working:

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT RegistrationID, ID,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY RegistrationID )) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM tblData_Visit
            WHERE RegistrationID = @baseid
) 
SELECT ' ' + CAST(RowNumber AS nvarchar) AS 'Row#'     
FROM MyTable 
WHERE RegistrationID = @baseid AND ID = @objectid
```

When I create a stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[upMeta_VisitIndex]
(
@baseid int,
@objectid int
)
AS
WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT RegistrationID, ID,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY RegistrationID )) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM tblData_Visit
    WHERE RegistrationID = @baseid
) 
SELECT ' ' + CAST(RowNumber AS nvarchar) AS 'Row#'     
FROM MyTable 
WHERE RegistrationID = @baseid AND ID = @objectid


GO
```

, and call it using:

```
EXEC upMeta_VisitIndex @baseid @objectid
```

I end up in errorville:

```
SQL exception data:
SQL error number: 102. SQL state:1. Error class: 15. Message: "Incorrect 
syntax near '@objectid'.". Procedure:"".
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 
'@objectid'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, 
Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)...............
```

Given, I know @baseid and @objectid are not null, I think the issue is around how I am calling the SP. Is there anything obvious here that I am missing?

Cheers,
Gav.

Comment: `@baseid, @objectid`. A long question for one missing character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your EXEC statement while calling the stored procedure

```
EXEC upMeta_VisitIndex @baseid, @objectid
```

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be missing a comma between parameters when calling the stored procedure. Try this:

```
EXEC upMeta_VisitIndex @baseid , @objectid
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. Our pal Rahul down there also answered (hopefully spotted it himself), and giving the benefit of the doubt I want to give him the rep boost, in the hopes that someday , I too make it to a double digits rep! haha

Comment: haha good luck.

Comment: Thank you @GavinCreagh and Greg, yes I had spotted the error, but as soon as I posted the answer the page refreshed and I realized that Greg had answered a few minutes ago. Appreciate the kind gesture, and I now finally have enough reputation points to be able to comment here, and thank you!